# ¿Cómo abrir puertos netvanta 3448?

Tags: iron-router

Hola estoy haciendo unas pruebas de redes y la cuestión es como poder abrir puertos en un netvanta 3448 por cli en telnet.

He revisado en la documentacion pero no encuentro la parte parar abrir puertos.